# Genetics question on recombination frequency

Tags: genetics, botany, homework

A space probe discovers a planet inhabited by creatures that reproduce with
the same hereditary patterns seen in humans. The phenotypic characters are
height (T=tall, t=dwarf), head antennae (A-antennae, a=no antennae). For
heterozygotes with tall and antennae phenotype, the offspring are: tall-
antennae, 47; dwarf-antennae, 2; dwarf-no antennae, 40; tall-no antennae, 11.

What is the recombination frequency for the experiment?

A)13%

2)2%

3)87%

4)11%

The recombination frequency can be calculated by dividing the number of
offspring with a different combination of traits than their parents by the
total number of offspring and multiplying by 100 to express the result as a
percentage. In this case, there were 47+2=49 offspring with a different
combination of traits than their parents, and a total of 47+2+40+11=100
offspring. Dividing these values and multiplying by 100 gives us
49/100*100=49%, but how we get 13%

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please take a [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on the Biology Stack. In particular note the [homework](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) policy - askers here, particularly for questions that are obviously homework, are expected to show some attempt at answering their own question.

Comment: You don't seem to have the original phenotypes for the actual parental types (F0s), only their children the F1s (all of whom are apparently tall/antennae, e.g. dominant characters one supposes), whose apparently random mating yields the F2 generation (with the 4 types you are counting). In the absence of other information, one supposes that the non-parental types are dwarf-antennae and tall-no antennae. Is that correct? Do your numbers really add up? Do you know the F0 (parental) types? Check again.